# How to do an ets table lookup using a secondary key

Tags: erlang, mnesia, erlang-shell, ets

I have a table with the following attributes:

```
SortCode   Index  Created
```

`SortCode` is the primary key and `Index` is secondary key. Given an `Index` value, how do I get the associated `SortCode` value?

I have tried `ets:lookup/3` but it takes only a primary key.

Comment: You should include the code so we can see what you're putting into the table as a value. Either way, have a look at the [`ets:match` functions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#match-2).

Comment: You can use ets:match/2 or ets:select/2 to find the table entries with an Index value however will result in each entry of the table being read which is much less efficient ets:lookup/2.
You may implement your table with mnesia where you can maintain multiple indexes in a table and use mnesia:index_read/3 to efficiently lookup with the secondary indexes.

Answer (score 3):

There is not such thing as a secondary index in `ets`. You can do:

1. full scan using `ets:match` or `ets:select` or
2. make you own reverse index `ets` table or
3. use `mnesia` with added (secondary) index.

Answer (score -2):

Adding to what Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil has said.

There is no solution in ets to fetch record using some other attribute apart from the key. It can be done using `mnesia:dirty_index_read()`.

If you want to use ets only then you can do as above suggestion or follwoing code. Assuming your record pattern is omething like : `{"one",1,"27092015"}`
Key is "one" but you have to fetch using 1.

```
FilterSuspCodeFun = fun ({_,I,_}) when I == 1 -> true ; (_) -> false end,
ListData = ets:tab2list(susp_code),
{SortCode,_,created}= lists:filter(FilterSuspCodeFun,ListData),
```

Comment: It is very inefficient way how to do `ets:select(susp_code, [{{'_', 1, '_'}, [], ['$_']}]).` You can generate match specification using `ets:fun2ms(fun({_, 1, _} = R) -> R end).`

Comment: This is just factually wrong. You can absolutely fetch records from ETS without using the key. This is exactly what `match` and `select` functions are for. They may not be as fast as a primary key lookup, but that doesn't mean there is no solution. And the solution you present is the worst possible of all solutions. For a ~100MB table, it was 5x slower than `match` and `select`, and had 1300x the memory usage.